# UITableView not updating correctly when scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I am writing a UITableView that contains 2 sections. When the table first loads all the cells are displaying the correct info, but when I start scrolling up and down, cells detailedTextLabel and accessoryType are being refreshed incorrectly, such that some cells that should only contain a detailedTextLabel also contain an accessory, and cells that should only contain an accessory also contain a detailedTextLabel.

Inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I am using nested switch/case statements to apply the correct values to the cells in their respective section/row. As far as i can tell the logic in these statements is correct, so is it possible that the value of `cell` variable is inccorect when updating?

The table loads correctly but after scrolling accessoryType and detailedTextLabel gets mixed up.

[Click for link to screen shots of the table.](http://www.flickr.com/photos/57059764@N07/5263568952/)

Here is the code inside of my UITableViewController subclass:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [sectionNames count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSArray *headingsSection = [cellTitles objectAtIndex:section];
    return [headingsSection count]; 
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [sectionNames objectAtIndex:section];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    self.tableView.allowsSelection = YES;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[cellTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]; 

    switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%%", [[assistSettingsArray_glob objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue]];
        break;
    case 1:
        switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            break;
        case 2:
            if (defaultAssistOn) {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            } else {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            }
            break;
        }
        break;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Due to cell re-use, cells with previously set values re-appear.

Before the `switch (indexPath.section) ...`, initialize the detailTextLabel and accessoryType to defaults:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

Comment: Additionally if you decide to add subviews to the content view, you would need to remove those with something like `[[[cell contentView] subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];`

Comment: Oh great, that has fixed the problem perfectly. Thanks very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to enclose the code in each switch cases inside parantheisis. So the above code looks like this:

```
switch (indexPath.section) {
   case 0: {
       cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%%",
               [[assistSettingsArray_glob objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue]];
       break;
     }
   case 1: {
       switch (indexPath.row) {
          case 0: {
              cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
              break; }
         case 1: {
             cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
             break; }
         case 2: {
             if (defaultAssistOn) {
               cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            }
            else{
               cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            }
            break; }
        default:
            break;
       }
       break;
     }
    default:
    break;
  }
```

I am not sure whether this work. Do inform if it does :)

Comment: The previous answer actually solved the problem. Thanks for your help.