# Flushing UITableView queue for cells

Tags: iphone

I was wondering if some one can please reply me with if the UITableView queue gets flushed when UITableView reloadData is called.I am trying to do so and this isnt helping me.Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you call the UITableView "queue" ?

Answer (score 8):

if you look at the header file for UITableView, you can see that there is a private NSMutableDictionary (iVar) called "_reusableTableCells". This is a dictionary with cell reuse identifiers as key and with array with cells that are currently offscreen as value.

If you want to manually flush queued cells in way that may change with the implementation, you can do so in ugly manner, like so:

```
NSMutableDictionary *cells = (NSMutableDictionary*)[self.tableView valueForKey:@"_reusableTableCells"];
[cells removeAllObjects];
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Is this kosher for the App Store?

Answer (score 4):

Once the table is loaded, the cells are reused. Reloading the table does not flush the queue. `reloadData` calls `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`

In this method the `if(cell==nil)` condition is present so that cells are not flushed once they have been loaded into memory, and therefore reused.

To get around this you reset your cells before applying the correct information.

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

Or if you are using an `accessoryView`

```
cell.accessoryView = nil;
```

Also take a look at this example. [UITableView not updating correctly when scrolling.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450366/uitableview-not-updating-correctly-when-scrolling)