# How to discard all table cells associated with a UITableView so as to refresh them

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I create my table cell once, as its a slow process due to all the images on the cell.
Its very rare anything changes, but there is a rare case where I want to the cells completely.

The code that gets a cell is

```
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PlaceholderCellIdentifier];
```

if there is no associated cell I create one.

```
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PlaceholderCellIdentifier];


if (cell == nil)
{
    //create cell
    return cell;
}
else
{
    return cell;
}
```

Is there a way to dump all of the reusable cells that are associated with this table? So when I call

```
[table reloadData];
```

It will generate a fresh set of cells?

Many Thanks,
-Code

Comment: If you need small, fixed amount of cells you can just not dequeue reusable cells, but always create new one. When you create a cell, put nil as cell Identifier.

Comment: Why can't you just reuse past cells and refresh them, instead of tossing them away to make new ones?

Comment: xcode is just an IDE and irrelevant for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to this answer you can.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6164346/243192) However I *strongly* advice against this. It is bad practice to meddle with class internals.

Apart from that I don't see why you would want to do this. The reusing of cells is there to actually speed up the process and to keep down used memory. I don't see how creating a cell from scratch could actually be quicker than reusing one.

Answer (score 1):

Just reuse the existing cells. There is no need for deallocating the existing ones.

I guess that you wanted to ask the question differently. You may wanted to ask how to enforce the table view to re-display every cell with updated data ... ? If so then the answer is to use call

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

(assuming that you place the call within the table view controller)